# Using powershell loop with net.exe command error

Tags: asp.net, .net, powershell

I'm trying to use powershell to write a script that calls net.exe's delete on a collection of computers meeting the specific case of having 3 or fewer files open. I'm fairly new at this, obviously, as I'm getting odd errors.

Using the example at [Microsoft's blog](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4244.how-to-convert-text-output-of-a-legacy-console-application-to-powershell-objects.aspx) I made the function below out of `net session`.

```
Function Get-ActiveNetSessions
{
    # converts the output of the net session cmd into a PSobject
    $output = net session | Select-String -Pattern \\
    $output | foreach {
        $parts = $_ -split "\s+", 4
        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            Computer = $parts[0].ToString();
            Username = $parts[1];
            Opens = $parts[2];
            IdleTime = $parts[3];
        }
    }
}
```

which does produce a workable object that I can apply logic to.

I can use
`$computerList = Get-ActiveNetSessions | Where-Object {$_.Opens -clt 3} |   Select-Object {$_.Computer}` to pull all computers with less than three opens into a variable, too.

What fails is the loop below

```
ForEach($computer in $computerList)
{
    net session $computer /delete
}
```

with the error

```
net : The syntax of this command is:
At line:5 char:5
     net session $computer /delete
   CategoryInfo          :NotSpecified (The syntax of this command is::String) [], RemoteException
   FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

NET SESSION
[\\computername] [/DELETE] [/LIST]
```

Trying to run it with a call of `$computer = $computer.ToString()` ahead of the execution so it sees a string causes the script to hang without dropping the sessions, forcing me to close and reopen the ISE.

What should I do to get this loop working? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Net session expects a `\\` before the server name, it looks like.  Have you given that a try?

Comment: Actually the command does dig out the `\\000.000.000.000` formatting properly when I use just `Get-ActiveNetSessions |  Select-Object {$_.Computer}` which is why it's confusing me that Net Session is saying it's wrong.